# Using Eclipse Papyrus in RCP

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-rcp

Is it possible to use Papyrus UML editor, as a part of RCP - based application? We want to edit our domain model in UML notation, and there is so much tools in eclipse modeling project, that picking the right one is really difficult.

Answer (score 0):

Papyrus provides out of the box standard UML2 and SysML models. It is very easy to add a context menu for a specific model editor and to access the model by using the Eclipse UML2 model.

If you wish to use your own domain model, you have to create an own editor. As far as I know, this is also possible with the use of papyrus.